# Accessing Raw Data on DVR Formatted Hard Disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I need to access the data stored on hard drive that was used in Lorex DVR system.  The drive gets formatted by the DVR when installed.  I am trying to mount that drive in Linux but to no avail.

fdisk shows the partition as "Microsoft Basic Data".
parted shows the partition as "msftdata"

There is two partitions, the second is also listed as msftdata but it has a File System type of ext2, and I can mount this drive.  There is no video files here, just configs.

The first partition stores the video files.  There is no File System type listed in parted, it is just blank.  Trying to mount this drive with mount command gives error:  wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on ..., missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Anyone know a way to mount this partition in Linux so I can process the video files directly from the drive instead of manually doing so through the DVR system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research lead me to the following page (https://sleuthkit.discourse.group/t/support-for-dhfs-file-system-or-unknown-file-system/2006), where it was revealed to me that the file system is most likely DHFS (Dahua File System), and that it could be accessed using the Dahua Toolbox DiskManager software.  Indeed the DiskManager software within Dahua Toolbox allows me to access the partition without the DVR itself (by using a Windows).